# Adding Wildcard Elements to a Generic Container Class

Tags: java, generics, collections, wildcard, addition

So I need to add all elements from an `ArrayList<?>` to some kind of `ContainerClass` with generic type `<T>`
The method looks like this:

```
public class GenericOperations {
 public static <T> void insertElems(ContainerClass<T> container, ArrayList<?> array) {
   //How do I add elements from array to the container
 }
}
```

I thought you couldn't add wildcard elements to any `Collection`, but it has to be possible. I know you can't do it if the types of `T` and `?` don't match but in case it would be possible, how do I check if `?` has a compatible type to be added to the `Container<T>`?

I am not allowed to change the method signature.

Comment: The container takes specific elements, the array list has elements of any type (`<?>`) . The type of the elements obtained from the array list is not guaranteed to be compatible with the type of the container, hence the error

Comment: "*I am not allowed to change the method header*" You mean the signature? Then you are out of luck unless you cast the elements, which may throw an exception at runtime.

Comment: @Michael yes I know that, but thats my assignment so there has to be a way right?
Ah ok so casting is the only option, thats what I wanted to know

Comment: How are we supposed to answer that without any knowledge about that mysterious `ContainerClass`? The other comments assume that it follows the logic of collections or even is a subtype of `Collection<T>`, but without an explicit statement, that's just guesswork.

Comment: @Holger It's not exactly "guesswork". It's a reasonable presumption. Of course, it's *possible* that `ContainerClass` has an `add(Object o)` method, but I would put money on it that it doesn't.

Comment: @Michael or it's `class ContainerClass<X> extends AbstractList<Object>`. We simply don't know. Of course, it's reasonable to assume that it is rather `Collection<T>`, but the OP insists on having an assignment exactly in this form and there must be a reason why the parameter type is not `Collection<T>` in the first place and the OP should clarify this.